# Considerations for EMET features when making programs

Tags: visual-c++, compatibility, windows

I'm currently in a project for a small C++ windows game application and its library.

Recently I found that [Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit (EMET)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29851) could be used on the client's PC to improve security.
I have toyed with EMET and even an application from Microsoft (e.g. sidebar.exe) hasn't been compatible with it, so it must require several special cares for programs to be compatible with EMET features such as ASLR or EAF.

What should I take into account to make my programs compatible with EMET features?
Is there any options for compilers or restrictions of workflow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMET is for legacy software which you cannot get their code utilize unavailable-unless-rebuilded security features.
If you can rebuild your software, [refer to this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430720.aspx) to enable them.

Comment: I misunderstood what EMET is used for... I leave this question to make pointers for information more available.